# Exporting map error from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, image, png

Whenever I try to export a map as an PNG image I get the 'successfully export' message but there is no file generated. The error happened in Zanzibar so I changed to Noosa but I still can't export the map.

It has never happened to me before so I guess it might be a problem with my system.

Does anybody have any idea of what is happening?

Comment: windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Also, some more side-info would be of benefit: type of map and layers (for example: are all layers physical files on your computer or are they obtained via web services?), where (path) you are trying to save the PNG, etc.

Comment: Here's some basic troubleshooting you can do: 1. Export to a different folder, preferably one with a short file path without spaces. 2. Reduce the DPI/image quality/resolution of the output. 3. Create a blank project, make a map with a single vector layer that you have physically stored on your computer, see if you can export that. 4. Do the same as 3, but with a raster layer. Update your answer and let us know which, if any, of those methods lets you export a map. This will help narrow down where the problem lies.

Answer (score 6):

In the Layout, right click on the page and choose "Page Properties...". In the side panel "Item Properties", make sure "Exclude page from exports" is unticked.