# QGIS 3.4 Not Exporting Map to JPEG, JPG, PNG, PDF

Tags: export, jpg

I'm using 3.4 version, and unable to export my map as different image types. It immediately says my export was successfully saved, but when I navigate to the folder it says I saved it in, nothing is there at all. This happens when I save as a JPEG, JPG, PNG, PDF.

Thoughts?

Comment: OS? Linux, Mac, Windows. Writable folder? See also comments for https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337472/exporting-map-error-from-qgis (PS: no answer but good advices to troubleshoot)

Comment: Many amounts of layers and raster backgrounds with high dpi export can lead to strange things, can you give a few more details please?

Comment: After export completed you get a small, green infoline informing you that the output was successfully completed. Do you get this info? Did you click it? It opens the output folder.

Comment: Thanks for the input, all.  I'm using Windows OS, tried exporting to a different folder, but unsuccessful.  Upon exporting, I'm increasing from 300 dpi to 350 dpi, which is the level of res needed for our publication.  I get small, green infoline babel mentioned, but when I click on it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: I deleted unwanted layers and set the layout to landscape. It did work.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a new layout. I had little elements to add so it worked